# How to intercept the Websocket call in Crossbar+Autobahn

Tags: websocket, autobahn, crossbar, autobahnws

I want to know if it is possible to implement some interceptor to check user authentication in websocket RPC. 
My use case is

1. User registers himself with some token using URI 'com.safe.reg'
2. Token is validated and cached against the sessionid
3. For next call to some other URI (say 'com.bus.op1') I want to ensure that the token is still valid and hence want to call something which will check the cached token for the sessionid.

I want this to happen for every business call and also, I don't want to send the session id as parameter in the function call.

This is typically handled in the interceptors in http request-response communication. How can we achieve this in websockets while using crossbar?

Comment: I don't fully get your use case, but do dynamic authorizers (http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/#dynamic-authorization) help here?

Comment: Thanks @gzost for sharing your views. I am indeed trying to build a solution as combination of dynamic authentication+dynamic authorization and details. I will post the same in a few days if successful.